# Polling the keyboard (detect a keypress) in python

Tags: python, console, keyboard, blocking, nonblocking

How can I poll the keyboard from a console python app? Specifically, I would like to do something akin to this in the midst of a lot of other I/O activities (socket selects, serial port access, etc.):

```
while True:
    # doing amazing pythonic embedded stuff
    # ...

    # periodically do a non-blocking check to see if
    # we are being told to do something else
    x = keyboard.read(1000, timeout = 0)

    if len(x):
        # ok, some key got pressed
        # do something
```

What is the correct pythonic way to do this on Windows? Also, portability to Linux wouldn't be bad, though it's not required.

Comment: Just to let other people know, I found that most solutions involving select or thread libraries did not work correctly from IDLE. However, they _**all**_ worked fine on the CLI i.e. `python /home/pi/poll_keyboard.py`

Comment: In general I think reacting to key presses instead of polling them periodically is more robust solution as you are not potentially missing the key presses. See my answer below.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The standard approach is to use the [select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) module.

However, this doesn't work on Windows.  For that, you can use the [msvcrt](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html#console-i-o) module's keyboard polling.

Often, this is done with multiple threads -- one per device being "watched" plus the background processes that might need to be interrupted by the device.

Comment: Correct me if i’m wrong, but in my experience msvcrt only works when you run the program in a command window, ie. not in IDLE and not with a GUI...

Comment: @digitalHamster0: Anything that replaces `sys.stdin` with a custom object (e.g. IDLE, most GUIs) would have that effect. When `sys.stdin` isn't a true file, you can't use `select`; when it's not connected to a "real" console, you can't use the `msvcrt` keyboard polling functions (that implicitly rely on a "real" console).

Comment: In general I think reacting to key presses instead of polling them periodically is more robust solution as you are not potentially missing the key presses. See my answer below.

Comment: If you could a minimal working example, that will be great. The link does not provide enough information.

Answer (score 23):

A solution using the curses module.  Printing a numeric value corresponding to each key pressed:

```
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    # do not wait for input when calling getch
    stdscr.nodelay(1)
    while True:
        # get keyboard input, returns -1 if none available
        c = stdscr.getch()
        if c != -1:
            # print numeric value
            stdscr.addstr(str(c) + ' ')
            stdscr.refresh()
            # return curser to start position
            stdscr.move(0, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: OZ123: It can. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417379/what-is-needed-for-curses-in-python-3-4-on-windows7

Comment: Had issues using curses via SSH term on headless host.  Issues were badly messing up the terminal - requiring it to be `reset` between each run.  It did work, i.e. detect keypress.  There has to be a smarter solution.

Answer (score 18):

None of these answers worked well for me. This package, pynput, does exactly what I need.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: This worked for me, except the key pressed was echoed to the screen immediately after being pressed, and there was no way to disable it.

https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/47

Plus, the characters are buffered and additionally appear on the command line when the program exits too.This appears to be a limitation of the Linux implementation, but it works fine on Windows.

Comment: This solution doesn't work when the script runs via ssh. It bombs out with the error: 'Xlib.error.DisplayNameError: Bad display name "".'

Comment: As mentioned above by David - this is not a good solution for headless instances as it has a dependency on Xserver.  `import Xlib.display`

Answer (score 17):

Ok, since my attempt to post my solution in a comment failed, here's what I was trying to say.  I could do exactly what I wanted from native Python (on Windows, not anywhere else though) with the following code:

```
import msvcrt 

def kbfunc(): 
   x = msvcrt.kbhit()
   if x: 
      ret = ord(msvcrt.getch()) 
   else: 
      ret = 0 
   return ret
```

Answer (score 16):

```
import sys
import select

def heardEnter():
    i,o,e = select.select([sys.stdin],[],[],0.0001)
    for s in i:
        if s == sys.stdin:
            input = sys.stdin.readline()
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: no worky. got error: select.error: (10093, 'Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed')

Comment: I've heard, more than a couple times, that the select system call on MS Windows doesn't support regular file descriptors and only works on sockets.  (I don't know if the Python implementation of select() has ever worked around that under the hood).

Comment: what is this weird timeout for? It works for me with timeout=0 but not with 0.0001 as shown..

Comment: Windows 7 + python 2.7 returns error:     i,o,e = select.select([sys.stdin],[],[],0)
select.error: (10038, 'An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket')

Comment: For me, this only detects keypresses after I press Enter.

Comment: @frans: Presumably the timeout is there for when the input pipe has just been drained, but whatever is feeding the pipe has more data to send that wouldn't fit in the pipe buffer; you allow a small amount of time for the input process to refill the buffer before giving up.

Comment: Works on Mac, but only indicates pressing enter (or returning a typed line if changing the return statement). Would it be possible to return keypresses immediately? Combining with e.g. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/ (which returns individual keypresses but blocks)?

Comment: There's actually a non-blocking version of the `getch` method in comments, but it misses keypresses which occur whenever the program is outside of the `select` timeout. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/#c12

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.10, this does not detect anything until <enter> is pressed. :-\

Comment: @MarkSmith: That's because the program hasn't received the input until either enter or control-D (*) is pressed, it's still in the kernel's "line-editing buffer".  (If you press control-D with no characters in the buffer it will close the terminal.)   // For this to work on unix-like systems, the terminal must be set to 'raw' or 'cbreak' mode instead of 'cooked'. I think this is done through some ioctl on stdin.

Comment: @JonathanHartley: (See my previous comment.)

Answer (score 6):

From the comments:

```
import msvcrt # built-in module

def kbfunc():
    return ord(msvcrt.getch()) if msvcrt.kbhit() else 0
```

---

Thanks for the help.  I ended up writing a C DLL called PyKeyboardAccess.dll and accessing the crt conio functions, exporting this routine:

```
#include <conio.h>

int kb_inkey () {
   int rc;
   int key;

   key = _kbhit();

   if (key == 0) {
      rc = 0;
   } else {
      rc = _getch();
   }

   return rc;
}
```

And I access it in python using the ctypes module (built into python 2.5):

```
import ctypes
import time

# first, load the DLL
try:
    kblib = ctypes.CDLL("PyKeyboardAccess.dll")
except:
    raise ("Error Loading PyKeyboardAccess.dll")

# now, find our function
try:
    kbfunc = kblib.kb_inkey
except:
    raise ("Could not find the kb_inkey function in the dll!")

# Ok, now let's demo the capability  
while True:
    x = kbfunc()

    if x != 0:
        print "Got key: %d" % x
    else:
        time.sleep(.01)
```

Comment: How is this better than the built-in msvcrt.kbhit()?  What advantage does it have?

Comment: You are absolutely right!  I misread your post; I didn't realize there is a python module called msvcrt!  I just thought you meant "use the ms crt," and then I got drawn into thinking about threads and didn't connect the dots.  You are absolutely right.

Comment: I did the same thing with:

import msvcrt

def kbfunc():
   x = msvcrt.kbhit()

   if x:
      ret = ord(msvcrt.getch())
   else:
      ret = 0

   return ret

Comment: Please, do not use a lambda like that.  "x = lambda" is supposed to be spelled "def x():"  Saving a lambda confuses the n00bz and drives the experienced crazy trying to explain it.

Comment: LOL!  That's not a lambda.  that's how the "comments" field reformatted my attempt to drop code into a comment.  BTW saving a lambda confuses me too, and I am not a python n00b :-)

Comment: This solution really intrigues me. I find the msvcrt approach to be slow, even in "optimized" micro loops as many solutions here provide. About this refer to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954038/why-is-msvcrt-very-very-slow). Though this solution is not very portable.

Answer (score 5):

I've come across a cross-platform implementation of `kbhit` at http://home.wlu.edu/~levys/software/kbhit.py (made edits to remove irrelevant code):

```
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
    import msvcrt
else:
    import sys, select

def kbhit():
    ''' Returns True if a keypress is waiting to be read in stdin, False otherwise.
    '''
    if os.name == 'nt':
        return msvcrt.kbhit()
    else:
        dr,dw,de = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
        return dr != []
```

Make sure to `read()` the waiting character(s) -- the function will keep returning `True` until you do!

Comment: Is this still up to date?  When I call the select version, I always get content back in dr.  If it still works, can you put it in context?  I have a "while true" loop I'd like to bail out from if a key is pressed.

Comment: @Mastiff maybe you don't `read()` the waiting characters after detecting them as advised.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev where do you `read()` the character from?

Comment: @ThomasBrowne Stdin

Answer (score 4):

You might look at how [pygame](http://books.google.com/books?id=W8T2f7F_rs0C&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=pygame+keyboard+polling&source=web&ots=Chhw92jDrx&sig=lavBFmwAUzB06J5er8T-AHN4eWs&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=1&ct=result) handles this to steal some ideas.

Comment: PyGame event handling only works for GUI, not the console as the OP asked.

Answer (score 4):

I am using this for checking for key presses, can't get much simpler:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import curses, time

def main(stdscr):
    """checking for keypress"""
    stdscr.nodelay(True)  # do not wait for input when calling getch
    return stdscr.getch()

while True:
    print("key:", curses.wrapper(main)) # prints: 'key: 97' for 'a' pressed
                                        # '-1' on no presses
    time.sleep(1)
```

While curses is not working on windows, there is a 'unicurses' version,  supposedly working on Linux, Windows, Mac but I could not get this to work

Comment: There is also `windows-curses` on PyPI.

Answer (score 2):

One more option would be to use [sshkeyboard](https://sshkeyboard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library to enable reacting to key presses instead of polling them periodically, and potentially missing the key press:

```py
from sshkeyboard import listen_keyboard, stop_listening

def press(key):
    print(f"'{key}' pressed")
    if key == "z":
        stop_listening()

listen_keyboard(on_press=press)
```

Simply `pip install sshkeyboard` to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using 'pynput' module in python,
You press a key and it gets printed It's that easy!

1. PIP Install the module in command prompt, write following text and press enter

   `pip install pynput`
2. Run the following code:

   ```
   from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

   def pressed(key):
       print('Pressed:',key)

   def released(key):
       print('Released:',key)
       if key == Key.enter:
           # Stop detecting when enter key is pressed
           return False

   # Below loop for Detcting keys runs until enter key is pressed
   with Listener(on_press=pressed, on_release=released) as detector:
       detector.join()
   ```
3. You can end the loop with any key you want by changing `Key.enter` to some other key in the 8th line of the code.

Answer (score -1):

If you combine time.sleep, threading.Thread, and sys.stdin.read you can easily wait for a specified amount of time for input and then continue,
also this should be cross-platform compatible.

```
t = threading.Thread(target=sys.stdin.read(1) args=(1,))
t.start()
time.sleep(5)
t.join()
```

You could also place this into a function like so

```
def timed_getch(self, bytes=1, timeout=1):
    t = threading.Thread(target=sys.stdin.read, args=(bytes,))
    t.start()
    time.sleep(timeout)
    t.join()
    del t
```

Although this will not return anything so instead you should use the multiprocessing pool module you can find that here: [how to get the return value from a thread in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python)

Comment: Shouldn't that first line be:  t = threading.Thread(target=sys.stdin.read, args=(1,))

Comment: Won't this solution always sleep for 5 seconds, even if the user presses a key before that?