# Advanced Python Keyboard Events?

Tags: python, events, tkinter, keyboard, keypress

Is it possible to cleanly detect a key being held down in (ideally native) Python (2)? I'm currently  using Tkinter to handle Keyboard events, but what I'm seeing is that when I'm holding a key down, `Key`, `KeyPress`, and `KeyRelease` events are all firing constantly, instead of the expected `KeyPress` once and `KeyRelease` at the end. I've thought about using  the timing between events to try to differentiate between repeated firing and the actual event, but the timing seems inconsistent - thus, while doable, it seems like a pain.

Along the same lines, is there a nice way to detect multiple key presses (and all being held down?) I'd like to have just used `KeyPress` and `KeyRelease` to detect the start / end of keys being pressed, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: depends on the os ... but I believe you can use `kbhit`

Comment: I'm running Linux, just fyi

Comment: in that case I would look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292095/polling-the-keyboard-in-python

Answer (score 3):

Use a keyup and keydown handler with a global array:

```
keys = []

def down(event):
    global keys
    if not event.keycode in keys:
        keys.append(event.keycode)

def up(event):
    global keys
    keys.remove(event.keycode)

root.bind('<KeyPress>', down)
root.bind('<KeyRelease>', up)
```

Now you can check for multiple entries in `keys`. To remove that continuous behavior you described, you have to compare the previous state of `keys` after an event happens.

Comment: How is this solution?

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but the behavior that I've noticed is that the events keep firing - that is, both the keyup and keydown events fire repeatedly (keyup, keydown, keyup, keydown, etc...) while the key is being held down. If I'm not mistaken, storing the states won't help alleviate this issue?

Comment: Tested, and the same behavior seems to be happening - that is, with a single key depressed, the `keys` variable is cycling between one entry and 0 entries, i.e. `[]` and `[112]`.

Comment: I gave you a push in the right direction. Now you need to create a second list for the previous state that you can compare to the current state. This will allow you to determine a single key press.