# Why is msvcrt (very very) slow?

Tags: c, windows, cygwin, libc, msvcrt

I'm specifically asking about the old `msvcrt.dll`. Hasn't Microsoft updated that library in newer versions of windows? or is that exactly the same library that one can find in Windows 98 distros?

I tested msvcrt against Cygwin with a test program that calls `malloc` a lot of times by a singly linked list blocking queue with mutexes and semaphores. By `ifdef`s, the program can be compiled to use Posix functions or else use Windows API calls. When compiled by MinGW with WinAPI calls the only dependency it has is `kernel32.dll`, `ntdll.dll`, and `msvcrt.dll`, while when compiled by Cygwin with Posix functions, the program will depend on `cygwin1.dll`.

I at first simply assumed that the Cygwin version will run slower because of the extra emulation layer for Posix functions; it has to translate them to WinAPI calls. But it appears that it runs 4 times faster in my machine than the MinGW compiled native binary.

The documentation of Cygwin states that it uses a different libc called newlib, and certainly the Cygwin-compiled binary does not appear to depend on msvcrt. So is this making the huge speed difference?

I have also experienced before, that when a C program calls millions of `malloc`s, one that depends on `msvcrt.dll` will run many times slower than any others depending on newer `msvcrXX.dll`. They even ran slower than the same program running under a virtual machine linux.

What's wrong with `msvcrt.dll`? Should I avoid it whenever possible?

Comment: `msvcrt.dll`'s `malloc()` is basically just a `RtlAllocateHeap()` (or `HeapAlloc()`) wrapper. newlib's one is probably more sophisticated.

Comment: I can't imagine that the vast majority of Windows programs which use msvcrt.dll are hobbled by a "slow" malloc() function.  There's almost certainly something else in your test program that's slowing things down.  Profiling is almost always better than guessing.

Comment: @DanKorn You can see the code. http://ideone.com/3tIJiA

Comment: `msvcrt` isn't meant to be used by large numbers of programs, it's simply a bare minimum implementation so that there's *something* available on every Windows system. Yes, avoid it whenever possible - you're expected to use the standard library that came with your compiler.

Comment: To expand on @MarkRansom's comment, new MSVC runtimes are meant to be redistributed with applications.  [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn448963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has more details.  Not sure how the `malloc` performance compares though.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I don't see any significant difference between the disassembled code of `malloc!msvcrt` vs `malloc!msvcr100`. Both are just wrapping `HeapAlloc`, as was already mentioned, which you can also see in the distributed CRT source. I also tested both versions by allocating 512 MB in 1 KB blocks. Both always took about the same amount of time as measured by `QueryPerformanceCounter`. As to Cygwin, it possibly bypasses Win32 to create and manage its own heap via system functions such as `NtVirtualAlloc`.