# What is needed for curses in Python 3.4 on Windows7?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, curses, pdcurses

I have a running Python 2.7/3.4 installation on my Windows 7 (x64) machine. I would like to test curses on Windows.

Curses is installed but not working:

```
>>> import curses
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Tools\Python3.4.2\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ImportError: No module named '_curses'
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) says:

> The Windows version of Python doesn’t include the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses) module. A ported version called [UniCurses](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/UniCurses) is available.

So, the Windows installer of Python 3.4 installed curses with unresolved dependencies. One could name this a bug...

OK, I looked into UniCurses. It's a wrapper for [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/):

> UniCurses is a wrapper for Python 2.x/3.x that provides a unified set of Curses functions on all platforms (MS Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X) with syntax close to that of the original NCurses. To provide the Curses functionality on Microsoft Windows systems it wraps [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/).

Installing UniCurses via `pip3` results in an error:

```
C:\Users\Paebbels>pip3 install UniCurses
Downloading/unpacking UniCurses
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement UniCurses
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external UniCurses to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for UniCurses
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Paebbels\pip\pip.log
```

The link to SourceForge on Python's UniCurses site is dead. A manual search an SourceForge helped to find [UniCurses for Python](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyunicurses/?source=directory) again.

But, the UniCurses 1.2 installer can not find any Python installation in my Windows registry. (Python 2.7.9 and Python 3.4.2 are available).

I also looked into Public Domain Curses (PDCurses). PD Cureses 3.4 is from late 2008. So it's 7 years old. I don't believe it will work either with Windows 7 nor Windows 8.1 or Windows 10.

**Is there any way to get curses running on Windows with Python.**

(The Windows Python, not the CygWin Python!)

Comment: It probably can be made to work, since there is no basic incompatibility issue -- but going this way, you will have to learn how to modify UniCurses (and build *that*).

Comment: Christoph Gohlke has a Windows build of [curses](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses). Download curses‑2.2‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl and follow the instructions to [install a wheel](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#installing-from-wheels).

Comment: @eryksun Please write your comment as an answer, so I can vote on it. The installation went well.

Comment: Are you wedded to writing curses code, or do you need an equivalent API?  If the latter, I've hit and had to solve all these same issues for [asciimatics](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/asciimatics).  This package will give you a cross-terminal API that works on Windows 7, 8 and 10, plus a load of animation goodies...

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use curses cross-platform (Windows, MacOS, GNU/Linux) if you install manually for Windows or like other package in others.

1. Install wheel package. If you need more info about [wheel click here](http://pythonwheels.com/).
2. Go to [this repository](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).
3. Download a package with your python version, in example for python 3.4:

   ```
   curses-2.2-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
   ```
4. Install it (this command if for windows, in GNU/Linux install like other package)

   ```
   python -m pip install curses-2.2-cp34-none-win32.whl
   ```
5. Just include in your python script:

   ```
   import curses
   ```

You can use curses wrapper for python. Works in Fedora 25 in all terminals, and Windows 10 using git bash, powershell, or cmd.

Update:

- An alternative to curses in Windows [here](https://www.openhub.net/p/wcurses).
- Console user interface in Windows [here](https://github.com/urwid/urwid).
- An interesting tutorial [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-python6/).

Comment: As this question is a bit outdated ... Are there already Python 3.5 and 3.6 wheels?

Comment: You asked for python 3.4, I tried that version and it works. I seems doesnt exist in wheels, but exists version python 3.5 and 3.6 if you want to try.

Comment: @Paebbels Yes, I checked today and there are wheels for Python 3.5 and Python 3.6 as well (and the 3.6 version works for me OK).

Comment: Also, curses python works perfectly with Ubuntu app from Windows store.

Comment: I get this error when trying to accomplish this

Requirement 'curses-2.2-cp34-none-win32.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
curses-2.2-cp34-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Storing debug log for failure in /home/fishe203/.pip/pip.log

whats that mean and how do i fix it?

Comment: @JadeFisher, Are you using a GNU/Linux distro? whl is only for Windows, in MAC and GNU/Linux use common ncurses packages.

Comment: @vgonisanz Im using a bash shell on windows

Comment: I installed python with windows installer and tested it from cmd. I don't know if works for cygwin of similar bash shells, but if you install python using cygwin and install the whl from there, it could works. Another option (for Windows 10) is using Linux subsystem (Ubuntu, Fedora...) and GNU/Linux stuff.

Answer (score 18):

Now we can easy install on python 3.7 using `pip install windows-curses`

Answer (score 9):

You can try [my mirror of unicurses](https://github.com/Chiel92/unicurses), which includes pdcurses dlls. I have it currently up and running on windows 7 with python 3.5.0.

To quickly test if it works for you, just clone the repository and create and run a python script within its toplevel directory containing something like

```
from unicurses import *
stdscr = initscr()
addstr("hello world")
getch()
```

Comment: I'll test it on my computer.

Comment: I'm not sure. But I wanted to fix a few things, and have a github mirror anyway. I notified the original author about the things I fixed, but I can't remember having gotten a response from that.