# How to move cursor in Windows consoles?

Tags: python, windows, console

I have been trying to make a progress bar above the input prompt, like this:

```
Array A 37/56 |  66,07% [=============-------]
Enter A[38]: _
```

However to do that I need to be able to move the cursor around to rewrite the above lines.

Searching around, I only found ways to do it in the UNIX/Linux terminal, but I am a Windows user. I run Python on Windows PowerShell and the Command Prompt, so those ways didn't work.

Is there any way to achieve this or is this just isn't possible in Windows?

Comment: Look for a curses emulator that runs on Windows. I think there are several available.

Comment: For example, please refer this article. [What is needed for curses in Python 3.4 on Windows7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32417379/9014308)