# Curses crash on execute (Python 3.7.2 on Windows 10)

Tags: python, curses

Found out about Curses a couple days ago and wanted to start messing around with it to see what I could create.
I followed some instructions for installation on another thread and it installed just fine. However, when I attempt to run initscr() (which initializes the screen, it crashes)

**Here's the Error text:**

{`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ADimi\Desktop\Wing Workspace\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
  File "C:\Users\ADimi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 30, in initscr
    fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'`}

**To recreate:**

You can run this in either, idle or a seperate file. For me this directly causes the error, specficially line 2. `stdscr = curses.initscr()`

`import curses
 stdscr = curses.initscr()`

From what I'm understanding from the error itself, `_sys.__stdout__`  is returning a NoneType and thus leading to a crash.

I tried to find similar issues online and have had no luck. Any help at this point could help out a lot I'd love to get this working.

Here's a link about curses:
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html#curses-howto

Here's where I found out about curses, the first comment is the installation instructions I followed:
[What is needed for curses in Python 3.4 on Windows7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417379/what-is-needed-for-curses-in-python-3-4-on-windows7)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I have some what found a fix. There is a windows tailored version of curses found here: https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/#files

After uninstalling the old curses and installing this you must follow some intermediate steps:

Create a file with this test code:

```
import curses
import time

screen = curses.initscr()
screen.clear()

time.sleep(4)
```

Create a path for 'python' for your cmd prompt:
https://www.pythoncentral.io/add-python-to-path-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Now using the cmd prompt open the file:

```
python test.py
```

You should be presented with a black screen for 4 seconds, then it will close.

This is the only work around I've come across, I will keep searching and updating as I go thank you.

Comment: Copy and paste your errors as text,  not as an image. Also, please include a [mcve].

Comment: How did you install curses?

Comment: @thebjorn I found the appropriate package here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ Then, using the cmd console I ran the wheel file and it installed.

Comment: I don't think you're ever going to get `curses` working inside IDLE, as you're not talking to a real terminal.  But this failure in a standalone script is puzzling.  Wild guess: try `import sys; sys.__stdout__ = sys.stdout` at the top, that should at least bypass the immediate error.

Comment: @jasonharper that does appear to bypass the immediate error, but a new error appears. It claims unsupported operation for fileno. I did some digging online and managed to find some claims backing what you said. It appears that it just doesn't work on idle. I am however, able to launch successfully in command line