# Is it possible to intercept key presses with python?

Tags: python

Is there a way to intercept key presses in python? By this I mean, suppose I'm in a notepad document, I want my script to detect the keys that I am pressing while I have notepad open, however I want my script to block the key presses from reaching notepad. I am on windows, using python 3.6.

Comment: You can use the `curses` library for that. Check the answer from @vgonisanz at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417379/what-is-needed-for-curses-in-python-3-4-on-windows7 for the installation instruction

Comment: How exactly would you do this with curses? Would it be possible for you to pin point me to anything related to this? Thanks!

Comment: curses won't do. You need an automation/keyboard macro binding. The keyboard module might work.