# How would I intercept key inputs on windows?

Tags: python, windows

How can I catch a key press in my program, but it won't be caught by other applications?

I know this is possibly a dupe of [Is it possible to intercept key presses with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565365/is-it-possible-to-intercept-key-presses-with-python) but I did not find any descriptive answers in there.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you read in  keys in your python program? Yes. That's what the `input` function is for. Will other applications see that keypress? Literally no way to answer that because as long as a program has the right OS permissions, it can look at whatever it wants. It's how debuggers work. So _can_ it be seen by other programs? Sure, with a lot of work. _Will_ it be seen? Not a question that has an answer. Is it _likely_ to be seen? No, but that information isn't useful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea. We could create a quick "key-logger" script in Python using the [pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) library. The implementation is pretty simple and only entails the following lines of code (taken from the docs).

```
def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))


listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()
```

This [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvDvp.gif) shows how this would run.

However if you were looking for key presses to be entirely redirected to a Python program, then the solution will probably be more involved and probably entail some fiddling with the [keyboard buffer](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/7926/keyboard-buffer#:%7E:text=A%20keyboard%20buffer%20is%20a,are%20processed%20by%20the%20CPU.).