# Unable to install curses (python/windows 10)

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

I have tried to use

```
python -m pip install windows-curses
```

and the error that shows up is:

```
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement windows-curses (from versions: none)
```

I have also tried the method provided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41224335/10733096) and the same error shows up in my terminal window. How can I install Curses for Python/Windows 10 on my machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's your Python version? This library works on 2.7 and 3.5+.

I have installed here without problems.

I have tested in 3.6 and 3.7 and worked fine.

Try downloading wheel from https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/#files if you has the apropriate version of Python.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize my Python version was only 3.4!