# Python newline after input n characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a script that read the user input, but after n characters python create a newline.

Example:

> The user input the follow, after 'H','0' and '1' the script create e
>   newline and start to read the input again.
>
> ABCDEFGH
>
> 12345670
>
> HIJKLMN1
>
> 8900000

**I don't want the user to press "Enter" after 'H" or after the 8th character, instead python will put the cursor in a newline.**

Comment: Get three different inputs then!

Comment: use `Select` module for unix/linux and `msvcrt` module for windows to read stdin.
Also there is an portable implementation here https://repolinux.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/non-blocking-read-from-stdin-in-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect a key press and if that char is G 7 or N you can add a new line "\n"

You can check out this thread to see how you can detect keypresses.

[Polling the keyboard (detect a keypress) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292095/polling-the-keyboard-detect-a-keypress-in-python)

check out the bottom answer, it includes a package for easily detecting presses

---

**Update**

You will ned to use some keypress detection or something instead of while loop to do this "on the fly", but I think this will get you started;

(though this is working, while() is only there to show where onpress or what you come up with should be, can be removed and script works fine)

```
import sys
#you need to change while() with on_press from a click listener or something
        while(True):
            bytes = sys.stdin.read() #reads "string"
            size_of_stdin = len(bytes) #reads string length
                if size_of_stdin > 7: ## size greater than 7 print;
                    print "You won!!" # prints
                    print "\n\n" # newlines
```

Reason you need to detect keypresses is that you have to "execute" the script manually now.

> As in enter some text
>
> 1234567 (press enter)
>
> then ctrl+z and enter again. (just to make it harder :p)

Then it looks like this in your terminal

> 1234567
>
> ^Z
>
> You won!!

Hope you figure it out, let me know if anything is unclear or if you don't find a way to detect presses and execute on after 7 presses.

Comment: I don't know what character will be the last. So this approach don't suit to me. But thanks anyway, I update my question.

Comment: @JoaoVitorino Updated my answer now, let me know what you end up with