# Push ESC to terminate python script

Tags: python

Is there a way to set up my script so that with one push button I can quit() my script? I am trying to fix my script but because I use input simulation I can't do control-D or using mouse clicks.

Thanks!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292095/polling-the-keyboard-detect-a-keypress-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> try:
...     a = raw_input()
... except EOFError:
...     print "Exited"
... 
Exited
>>>
```

Use `EOFError` for `control-D`, `KeyboardInterrupt` for `control-C`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand; wouldn't that work only when the script runs to that point? I am looking for a way to, with one push of a button, terminate a running script, while the script runs in background or when I do whatever else.

Comment: I heard you can "use a thread to listen in the background" ?