# Python multiple paste hotkeys for different strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to find a way to have multiple hotkeys that will paste different strings in windows.

currently using (from so):

```
import os

def add_to_clipboard(text):
    command = 'echo ' + text.strip() + '| clip'
    os.system(command)

add_to_clipboard("this string is now in clipboard")
```

which will paste when Ctrl + v is pressed. Is there a way using os to add another command to os system that will paste when I press another custom hotkey, such as Alt + space?

Comment: I think you need to have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292095/polling-the-keyboard-detect-a-keypress-in-python)

Comment: [This project](https://github.com/n0xew/MultiClip) claims to do what you're after. You could look at the source code [here](https://github.com/n0xew/MultiClip/blob/master/Data/MultiClip.py) to see how.

Comment: If you're willing to consider something other than Python then AutoHotKeys does what you want and much more.