# How to get multiple characters input and processed without pressing enter MAC OS

Tags: python, macos, input, msvcrt, getch

I am trying to get multiple characters input to be processed without enter being pressed.

I read some other post and the answer is msvcrt module which is not available for MAC. And Getch() function only takes one character at a time.

Any other module or solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polling the keyboard (detect a keypress) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292095/polling-the-keyboard-detect-a-keypress-in-python)

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=95195