# In python, how to do make print_slow() faster or skip it by pressing enter or a key?

Tags: python

I know of the print_slow function to make a print looks like a human typing. however, how can i make it print out instantly or skip the slow typing to show the print immediately by pressing a key or enter?

```
    import sys,time,random
def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)

print_slow("Type something here slowly")
```

I have a sample code above, would anyone help me out?

Comment: Can't you just the builtin `print()` instead?

Comment: Non-blocking keyboard input would be useful here, I bet. Take a look at [Polling the keyboard (detect a keypress) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/292095/953482). Then you can poll for the enter key, and break out of your loop early.

Comment: As an aside, please be aware that `str` is a reserved word in Python, and shouldn't be used as a variable name.

Comment: @TylerMarques - Your advice is sound, but I need to correct you on one small point.  `str` is not a [reserved word](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords). It is, however, a [built-in type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str).

Comment: @Robᵩ Thanks for the correction. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `threading` trick to simultaneously print and wait for user input. Have a look at this code (pressing Enter key will tell program to print fast):

```
from threading import Thread
waiting_time = 0.05
def check():
    i = input()
    global waiting_time
    waiting_time = 0
Thread(target = check).start()

import sys,time,random

def print_slow(str):

    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(waiting_time)

print_slow("Type something here slowly")
```

Comment: The modification of a variable without synchronization is making me so uneasy, even though Python's GIL probably makes this work right.