# How to skip or accelerate slow printing in python?

Tags: python, performance

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50991461/21322099) but doesn't work in my case, I want to convert it in a function that prints slow but if I hit enter just completes the whole sentence. I tried this but doesn't work.

```
import time
import sys
from threading import Thread

def controlled_print(str):
    # Function to skip slow printing
    waiting_time = 0.08
    def check():
        i = input()
        global waiting_time
        waiting_time = 0
    Thread(target = check).start()
    
    # Function to do slow print
    def print_slow(str):
        for letter in str:
            sys.stdout.write(letter)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(waiting_time)
    print_slow(str)

controlled_print('This sentence should print instantly if I hit "Enter".')
```

Comment: You never call `print_slow` here.

Comment: Your code is with errors, please display working code and your tries to fix the problem.

Comment: I just fixed the errors and found my main concern... inside the "check" function I used "global" when there is no global waiting time variable, I fixed that and everything is working as expected. I guess I need to answer myself. @TimRoberts Why? I'm new here, and want to learn.

Comment: Your original code defined the `print_slow` function, but never called that function.  Your latest edit does call it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.