# Break out of loop by keystroke at end of interation

Tags: python, loops, break

I want to break out of a loop by a keystroke. But not at any time. I want the current iteration of the loop to finish up and then exit the loop.

All similar question I found mostly suggest catching KeyboardInterrupt, so I hope this is no duplicate.

Comment: Just check for keyboard interrupt at the end of the loop. If you got one, break out of it

Comment: @AndrewScott But KeyboardInterrupt is an asynchronous exception. You cannot "check for it", it arrives uninvited and interrupts whatever code is currently running, immediately.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of an iteration, check if there was a keypress by any of the methods listed in [Polling the keyboard (detect a keypress) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292095/polling-the-keyboard-detect-a-keypress-in-python) and break out of the loop if there was.

E.g. [with the cross-platform implementation of `kbhit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292095/polling-the-keyboard-detect-a-keypress-in-python/55692274#55692274):

```
while True:
    do_something()
    if kbhit(): break
```

Comment: thanks, I guess. The select module seems very complicated, though. You seem to be able to do a lot of advanced stuff with it. It really gives me a headache to understand all of it.
Could you provide a code example for my usecase using the select module?