# How to make python script more efficient while loop

Tags: python, performance, while-loop

I have a simple python script that listens to my keypress and executes a command upon keypress. In my code, I have an infinite while loop which is pretty harsh on the performance of my computer. I'm wondering what's a better way to achieve the same behavior with less impact on the performance. The objective is to print a text which says

> You Pressed A Key!

Every time I press a certain key, in this case, 'h', I want to be able to press h multiple times not just once hence the while loop.

```
import keyboard

while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('h'):
            print('You Pressed A Key!')
```

Comment: I think you want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53210441/2740650

Comment: I don't think a simple while loop will hinter the performance of your computer. In an average production application there are several demon while loop like this running.

Comment: And BTW as you seem to have guessed, we never loop like that (it's called a busy wait).  Instead we add callbacks to be notified of some action (in this case a key press).

Comment: @srth12 not sure if you noticed it's a tight loop (it's not event-driven).  So it's probably looping a few million times per second.  It's most definitely *not* what an average production app does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Polling the keyboard (detect a keypress) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292095/polling-the-keyboard-detect-a-keypress-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make the process sleep for a while using:

import time

time.sleep(number_of_seconds)